# What benefits does development mode offer in webpack?

Tags: javascript, debugging, webpack

I am using the command ...

```
webpack -w --mode development
```

but can not tell what benefits this adds.  I'm assuming it adds debugging benefits over production mode but I can not tell that it is doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

It sets the process.env.NODE_ENV to the value that you can use afterwards in your code accordingly afterwards

More information available here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

Answer (score -1):

You have access to sourcemaps (helps in debugging error), development server can be launched up which will restart everytime a file changes, no optimizations are done in development. moreover it's how we configure things for both modes

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/#root see this about sourcemaps and like I said it is how we configure things for both modes